# Get list item Analytics based on user

Tags: sharepoint-2007, c#-2.0

i am trying to get last 30 days information on single list item or document based on User, i saw this feature in third party mapilabs Analytics.

Is it possible to get this through object model, if so could you please point me in right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SP analytics in general provide things like on Site X, user Y did 24 things.  Or item X was accessed 34 times.

It usually doesn't provide things like on Site X, user Y did A, B and C or Item X was access 10 times by User A and 5 times by User B.  There are some privacy implications to those kinds of things in some countries.

What you can do however is mine the IIS logs if you still have them around.  Also if you have SharePoint Auditing enabled you can query the audit logs to get the information that you so desire.